# ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y%m%d'

Tags: python

Im receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2013' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

Here is the section of code where the error is occuring:

```
# Convert periodEndDate from string to datetime to epoch timestamp
            df['periodEndDate'] = df['periodEndDate'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(int(x), format='%Y%m%d').timestamp())
            df['periodEndDate'] = df['periodEndDate'].astype(int)
            df['periodTypeId'] = 1
            return df.to_dict('records')
```

output:

```
0        2013
1        2012
2        2015
3    20111231
4        2016
5        2014
6        2017
7        2018
```

I understand that the code is failing as '2013' does not match the format, is it possible to insert a day and month to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the format. Let pandas infer it.

```
df['periodEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df["periodEndDate"])

>>> df
0   2013-01-01
1   2012-01-01
2   2015-01-01
3   2011-12-31
4   2016-01-01
5   2014-01-01
6   2017-01-01
7   2018-01-01
Name: periodEndDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```